# bluebird promise each return results

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, promise, bluebird

im using bluebird to chain few phantom related tasks in nodejs. My problem is that the last then in the chain gets the argument passed to the each as its results instead of the results of scrapDomain function

I've been messing with this for 2 days now, help please?

Promise chain:

```
Promise
    .each(domains, function(domain) {
        return ensureDir(domain[0])
    })
    .each(ssHome)
    .each(function(domain){
        return scrapDomain(domain).then(function(results){
            return results
        })
    })
    .then(function(results){
            console.log(results)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html

> Resolves to the original array unmodified, this method is meant to be used for side effects. If the iterator function returns a promise or a thenable, then the result of the promise is awaited, before continuing with next iteration.

I think you want to use http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `mapSeries` which was designed exactly for this:

```
Promise
    .mapSeries(domains, function(domain) {
        return ensureDir(domain[0])
    })
    .mapSeries(ssHome)
    .mapSeries(scrapDomain)
    .mapSeries(console.log);
```

Although, personally I wouldn't write that code this way. First, `each` and `mapSeries` both execute *sequentially*, while other functions like `map` execute the function concurrently.

Second, in this use case each step has to wait for the previous step which is not necessary in your case. Instead, I'd write it like this:

```
const scrape = Promise.coroutine(d => { // Promise.coroutine is bluebird specific 
   let dir = ensureDir(d[0]);
   let home = yield ssHome(dir);
   let results = yield scrapDomain(home);
   return results;
});
```

And then do:

```
let results = Promise.map(domains, scrape);
```

Which would let you do:

```
results.then(items => console.log(items));
```